# Why did John Doe kill Tracy?

Tags: plot-explanation, se7en

In the conversation in the car between Doe, Somerset and Mills we see that Doe justifies the murders of all the people he killed according to the seven sins. But how can he justify killing Tracy?

Answer (score 10):

He don't (justify it). He killed her because he was envious of David and his life. Envy was his own sin.

> Doe: Because I envy your normal life, it seems envy is my sin.

Which made him the six sinner (a representative of the 6th sin). Then Mills will become the seventh sinner when he kills Doe.

> Doe: Become vengeance, David, Become wrath.

That's why Somerset while warning Mills not to kill Doe said

> If you kill him, he'll win.

Comment: I kind of have this theory that in the orginal writing, Mills puts the gun to his own head and blows it off in despair after shooting Doe. Its known the studio where pretty freaked out about Tracys head in a box and wanted it out, but the director fought hard agains that. I imagine if Mills blows his own brains out that might have been something the director could never have kept, and he likely knew it.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike his other kills, Tracy was not a Sinner that was killed but was a target as a consequence of envy. A sin that Doe himself committed. So basically she died without having been a sinner.

His plan was to reveal this to David so that upon knowing the fact, David would kill Doe for the Sin of Envy and become Wrath himself. Except unlike the other 6 sins that paid for the sins with Life, David's punishment would be to lose his wife.

Tracy died without having sinned but when you look at it as a whole, she died in advance for David's wrath. A sort of Catch22 if you ask me.

Answer (score 3):

Doe claims to represent the sin of "Envy" when he killed Mills wife; he was envious of Mills' normal life, and killed Tracy after failing to "play husband" with her. After that Mills kills Doe by shooting him repeatedly, becoming the embodiment of "Wrath".